# firefox: "event" not being exposed in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datepicker

In the jquery datepicker onSelect function, I'm trying to grab the selected element using event.target. In chrome, event.target is available to me but in firefox it's not. Everywhere I've looked tells me that in firefox, you just need to declare the event as a parameter but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
onSelect: function (dateString) {
  //first parameter is the dateString
  (function(event){
    console.log(event); //is undefined
  })();        
}
```

Shouldn't event be defined?

EDIT: What I'm trying to accomplish is determine which element was selected and grab the text. $(event.target).text() works in chrome but not firefox

Comment: I think it says to declare the **event** here `onSelect: function (dateString) {`

Comment: No, creating your own function inside another function is not magically make more parameters appear, than where available when the original, now “outside” function was called.

Comment: I tried to declare event in the onSelect function and the first parameter is the dateString. I looked in arguments as well

Answer (score 0):

You can almost always use `this` inside a jQueryUI widget callback to access the element the widget event occurred on.

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
      onSelect:function(){
        console.log('Datepicker id is:', this.id)
      }
    });
 });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


 
<p>Date 1: <input type="text" id="datepicker-1" class="datepicker"></p>
<p>Date 2: <input type="text" id="datepicker-2" class="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how I would access the element from here? This returns the datepicker

Comment: Access what element? You haven't identified exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @ProgrammingGodJK No it doesn't, `this` returns the input element.

Comment: @vi5ion and that would most likely be what you would want. If OP wants something else then it is completely unclear in question

Comment: @vi5ion when I console.log(this) in the onSelect function it returns the datepicker, not the selected element. I want something like this <a class="ui-state-default ui-state-hover" href="#">1</a> but this returns the entire calendar

Comment: @ProgrammingGodJK that is not exposed in the datepicker api. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do with that element?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm trying to determine which element was clicked so that I can handle different cases. If a calendar date is clicked, I want to do x. If prev/next month is clicked I want to do y. In chrome I can do $(event.target).text() but in firefox, event is not available to me so I was trying to figure out alternative solutions. I'll edit my question above if possible to be more clear.

Comment: Because `window.event` is a global in some browsers but not others. Is not a standard. Something wrong though about what you are encountering in general. I have used datepicker for many years and never seen what you are seeing

Comment: I think you should figure out why prev/next month is triggering `onSelect` because it shouldn't.

Comment: So weird... I don't see what I could be doing that would be triggering onSelect to fire outside of it's normal behavior but I'll investigate. Thanks both of you guys, upvoted both your answers

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQueryUI? Is it actually a jQueryUI datepicker( there are numerous datepickers around)? Create a demo in jsfiddle, codepen or other sandbox that reproduces problem

Comment: jQuery version is 1.8, not sure how to find datepicker version

Comment: Ok that's a fairly old jQuery version...what version of datepicker? I am guessing you might be using a different datepicker plugin than the one I referenced

Comment: Look inside it's source file. Probabl contains author info and links to docs/ repos

Comment: @charlietfl omg I found it... there's this one line of code hidden amongst the jumble that's triggering a calendar click on month select... thank you so much for your help

Comment: Ahhhh! ...   probably trying to select first day of month or something each month change. Seems like a strange user experience even trying to do that unless datepicker is always open

Comment: Ya I think that's exactly what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

The `onSelect` option is a Datepicker option, not an actual `event`.

Check the datepicker documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

If you want the active Datepicker instance, you need to pass a second parameter.
If you want the associated input field, then use `this`.

Comment: I want to find the exact element that was clicked. onSelect is triggered when clicking prev/next month as well as when selecting a date. I want to use the element's class/text or some kind of identifier to differentiate what was actually clicked

Comment: @ProgrammingGodJK *"onSelect is triggered when clicking prev/next month"* ... no it isn't.

Comment: @charlietfl It is for me 100%.... I was confused initially as well on why it's happening but it is. When I click on the prev/next arrows onSelect is firing.

Comment: Does that also happen in the snippet that charlietf posted or only in your own code? Because I just tested his snippet in multiple browsers and `onSelect` never gets triggered by prev/next month. Which makes me think there's something else going on in your code that might be causing it.

Comment: @ProgrammingGodJK create a demo that reproduces that. There is another callback `onChangeMonthYear` that would do that but not `onSelect`